# Calculating total cost and adding sales tax to shopping cart

Tags: django, calculator, cart

I am creating a basic shopping cart application, I can get in my cart all of the items to populate with the quantity and cost, but I am trying to find a way thats I can create a total cost, and adding sales tax on top of that. Clearly the total line is the issue, but I am not sure what I could do to populate price and quantity for all products and multiply them together.

```
{% for addtocart in userCart %}
  <li>Quantity:{{addtocart.quantity}} <a href="/products/{{addtocart.product.id}}">{{addtocart.product.prodName}}</a> ${{addtocart.product.prodPrice}}(<a
href=/delItem/{{addtocart.id}}>Remove</a>)<br>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p> No products available </p>
{% endif %}
***<p>Total: {{addtocart.quantity}}"x"{{addtocart.product.prodPrice}}***
```

views.py

```
def addtocart(request, prod_id):
        if (request.method == 'POST'):
                form = CartForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                        newComment = form.save()
                        newComment.session = request.session.session_key[:20]
                        newComment.save()
                        return HttpResponseRedirect('/products/' + str(newComment.product.id))
        else:
                form = CartForm( {'name':'Your Name', 'session':'message', 'product':prod_id} )

        return render_to_response('Products/comment.html', {'form': form, 'prod_id': prod_id})

def userHistory(request):
        userCart = Cart.objects.filter(session = request.session.session_key[:20])
        return render_to_response('Products/history.html', {'userCart':userCart})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

# Create your models here.
class prod(models.Model):
        prodName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        prodDesc = models.TextField()
        prodPrice = models.FloatField()
        prodImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="userimages/")
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.prodName

class Cart(models.Model):
        session = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        product = models.ForeignKey('prod')
        quantity = models.IntegerField()

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class CartForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
                model = Cart
                exclude = ('session')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this:

1. compute the total in your view, and pass it in as a separate variable
2. define a custom template tag that does multiplication (Django doesn't have one by default)

(1) in more detail:

In your view:

```
def userHistory(request):
    userCart = Cart.objects.filter(session = request.session.session_key[:20])
    totalCost = 0
    for item in userCart:
        totalCost += item.quantity * item.product.prodPrice
    return render_to_response('Products/history.html', {'userCart':userCart,
        'totalCost': totalCost})
```

Then in your template:
`<p>{{totalCost}}</p>`

(2) in more detail:

First make a new file my_app/templatetags/my_tags.py (also put an __init__.py file in this directory, so that Python knows it's a package)

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter 
def multiply(arg1, arg2): 
    return float(arg1) * float(arg2)
```

Then in your template add `{% load my_tags %}` at the top, and you'll be able to use `{{addtocart.quantity|multiply:addtocart.product.prodPrice}}`

Comment: Sorry for sounding dumb but I am looking more at scenario 1 and it isnt that straight forward to me (I am at a very beginners level). Inside my views.py I am unsure of what to put

Comment: Could you post your view function? That'll make it easier for me to show you an example

Comment: I don't see the userCart variable defined in your view anywhere. How are you passing that into the template?

Comment: def userHistory(request):
        userCart = Cart.objects.filter(session = request.session.session_key[:20])
        return render_to_response('Products/history.html', {'userCart':userCart})

Comment: Ok, see my updated answer. I assumed that Cart has a many to many relation named 'items', so you'll need to rename that if it's not right. If you need help with that, just post your models.py file, and I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Ok, I think it should work now. Take a look at the updated answer. btw, mind 'accepting' it with the checkmark if it works :)

Comment: I defintely will! I am getting this error now though 'function' object has no attribute 'product'

Comment: What line do you get that on?

Comment: totalCost += item.quantity * item.product.prodPrice

Comment: That's very strange. Can you print the value of 'item' in that loop? It should be a Cart instance, not a function...

Comment: `print item` then look in the terminal that you're running the django runserver in, and you should see the output when you go to that page

Comment: do i input in terminal after i run the server? I am getting -bash: command not found

Comment: No, edit the Python code to be:
`for item in userCart:
     print item
     totalCost += item.quantity * item.product.prodPrice`

note: there `print item` and `totalCost += item.quantity * item.product.prodPrice` need to be on separate lines

Comment: now i get 'Cart' object has no attribute 'name'
in my models.py for
class Cart(models.Model):
        session = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        product = models.ForeignKey('prod')
        quantity = models.IntegerField()

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

Comment: That's because there's no field named `name` on Cart, you should probably change that to `return self.session` or something like that

Answer (score 0):

quick note: you're not recording the price at the time of addition to cart. this might be an issue on some carts. depends on the shop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting this in your view, I would make it a function under your model. This way if you have to calculate the total elsewhere in your app, you don't have to reuse the same code.

The real problem is that you are using an incorrect model. Users have only one shopping cart, not many. So you should use the following models instead:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    session = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', related_name='items')
    product = models.ForeignKey('prod') 
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

Then, you add the total function to the Cart model:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    session = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(prod, through="CartProduct")

    def total(self):
        total = 0.0
        for item in self.items.all():
            total += (item.product.prodPrice * item.quantity)
        return total
```

I would also seriously recommend renaming the prod model to Product and renaming the fields as well to match Django naming conventions.